# Writing data to php file

Tags: php, html

Trying data taken from the form to inscribe another PHP file by using the file functions.php.
It works great, except that it only retrieves data from the form, but it doesn't retrieve/register data that I wish to input such as html tags that are required to properly operate the website.
I would be grateful for advice.

```
/** php function file dir: ‘/themes/dir/securedir/subdir/functions.php’ */
/** php form file dir: ‘/themes/dir/formsdir/subdir/forms.php’ */
function updateVesti() {
    If (isset($_GET['pn-path'])){
        /** path: ‘/themes/dir/pagedir/subdir/phpfile.php’ */
        $pn_path = $_REQUEST['pn-path'];
        $inputs = !empty($_REQUEST['novosti']) ? $_REQUEST['novosti'] : array();
        if(!$fhandle = fopen($pn_path,"w")){
            header("Location: ../error.php?err=updateVesti() fhandle razlicno od fopen");
            exit();
        }
        if (is_writable($pn_path)) {
            foreach($inputs as $value) {
                $val1 = '<li class="news-item"><a href="#">';
                $val2 = '</a></li></br>';
                $contents = $val1. $value. $val2; /** write only $value? */
                echo $contents;
                $novosti = $value .PHP_EOL;
                if (fwrite($fhandle, $novosti) === FALSE) {
                    header("Location: ../error.php?err=updateVesti() fwrit = false");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }else{
            header("Location: ../error.php?err=updateVesti() file is not writible");
        }
        fclose($fhandle);
        header('Location: ../dir/index.php');
        exit();
    }else{
        exit();
    }
}
```

strong text**

Comment: If you want to do that, just send the `.innerHTML` of an Element that wraps around your form, via AJAX, then `file_put_contents($fileName, $ajaxStringHere)` in PHP. Of course, I consider this a horrible practice. Data should remain separate from DOM structure. Use JavaScript AJAX to send data to the Server. Upon response, build your DOM. Data should be held on the Server in a database.

Comment: Totally agree with you PHPglue! Certainly my data are completely separate from the DOM structure using PHP and JavaScript Ajax XML to communicate with the DB server. What I did was silly mistake made probably by a tired, adding new variable '$contents', without having to predict in the final step of the Loop, or as I already said in my answer, did not have to use a new variable but the existing $Value to give changed content. I am indeed grateful to you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Аs we usually gets reliable solution! Leave aside the work for some time and the solution will appear on its own! Minor changes in the code name for the variable, and now works great! Probably from fatigue make such omissions, although surprising is that I failed to find a similar problem across the board! I hope this example will help someone, if nothing else to know that they should take proper rest to be fresh in the brain!

```
...
$value = $val1. $value. $val2; // instead of $content
    echo $value;
    $novosti = $value .PHP_EOL;
...
```